# Delete array c++ crash issue

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator, delete-operator

I have allocated an array of object as:

```
int numPlwDistanceClimb = 5;
int numFl = 6;
GRBVar** t_gd = 0;
t_gd = new GRBVar* [numFl];
GRBVar* x = 0;
x = model.addVars(numFl, GRB_CONTINUOUS);
for (int k = 0; k < numFl; k++)
{
    t_gd[k] = model.addVars(numPlwDistanceClimb, GRB_CONTINUOUS);          
}
```

I delete the arrays as follows but it does not work.

```
 delete x;
 for (int i = 0; i < numFl; ++i)
 {
      delete t_gd[i];
 }
      delete [] t_gd;
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead and all your problems will be handled.

Comment: you dont initialize every t_gd individually in this code

Comment: I don't see any code where you actually write into `t_gd`. If you call free on uninitialized pointers a crash is what you can expect.

Comment: I initialize t_gd now. But it does not work !!

Comment: And what does `addVars` look like? Does it return a pointer that was created with `new`?

Comment: @molbdnilo you can find addVars in here: http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/py_model_addvars.html

Comment: Since it's a C API at heart, you probably want `free` instead of `delete` on those.

Comment: @ThomasEdison -- *you can find addVars in here* -- Nowhere is it mentioned that a dynamically created object is returned that can be deallocated with `delete`.  If it isn't mentioned, don't assume.  An API that returns something that the client must deallocate would state as such.

Comment: @molbdnilo it works but does not free all variables. The leak reduces but not entirely.

Comment: @ThomasEdison *it works but does not free all variables* -- So did the API state that those addresses are allocated using `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`?  I think you're using the API incorrectly and overcomplicated your program using pointers.  I am assuming that the authors of the C++ interface would properly implement the objects being returned in that there is no need for you to be manually releasing memory.  The `addVars` function returns an object -- why not just use `std::vector<GRBVar> t_gd(numF);` and fill the vector with the return value of `addVars`?

Comment: What exactly is `model.addVars` returning? Your code expects return a (modified) new GRBVar()

Comment: I wrongly assumed that the C++ API was a thin C wrapper. A closer look at the C++ API overview yields this: "For example, `GRBModel::addVars` returns an array of `GRBVar` objects. It is the user's responsibility to free the returned array (using `delete[]`)." So you're missing the `[]`.

Comment: @molbdnilo it does not work and worse than using free variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have allocated an array of object as:

No you have allocated array of **pointers to** objects.
Which means you have to allocate every pointer in that array if you want to use it properly, otherwise attempt to use them would cause undefined behavior.

```
GRBVar** t_gd = new GRBVar* [numFl];

for (int n = 0; n < numFl; n++)
{
    t_gd[i] = new GRBVar;
    // Or set them to nullptr
}
```

Also if you need array of pointers in C++, you could use `std::vector`

```
std::vector<GRBVar *> t_gd;
```

Where you dont have to allocate, free resources and you have way more possibilities.

Also you can use [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr< GRBVar > > t_gd;
```

Comment: I miss some detail in my code last time. Please review it. Thanks

Comment: If `addVars` returns pointer to allocated memory it should be OK. Could you provide us this function please?

Answer (score 1):

You must at least put every element of t_gc to NULL, otherwise the array contains random values and when you delete those it will crash

```
GRBVar** t_gd = 0;
t_gd = new GRBVar* [numFl];

for (int i = 0; i < numFl; i++)
{
  t_gd[i] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: I miss some detail in my code last time. Please review it. Thanks

Comment: nulling should not be neccessary since any entry will be filled within the loop

Comment: How does model.addVars(numPlwDistanceClimb, GRB_CONTINUOUS);  create a pointer to GRBVar? With new or something else?